how to create UPC using asp.net web api
I am creating a standalone POS system and I am now in the process of finalizing the ProductEntity class. I am wondering how I can create a barcode or UPC/SKU (I am not sure what to use) that I can use as a reference when scanning or looking for an existing item. What attributes do I need for this? Should I add a new attribute for the UPC/SKU? I am still new to programming and I am using ASP.NET Web API.
Right now this is what my ProductEntity looks like
using src.Brands;
using src.Categories;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace src.Products
{
    [Table("Product")]
    public class ProductEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Barcode {  get; set; } = string.Empty;    
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public int StockQuantity { get; set; }
        public List<CategoriesEntity> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CategoriesEntity>();
        public BrandsEntity Brands { get; set; } = new BrandsEntity();
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}

I haven't tried method yet to achieve this. I am still confused.

Depends on what you want to do with it. If you want the barcode to just act as an id for a db lookup, then encoding the (unique!) ID would be sufficient. If your want to encode more data to be able to calculate stuff without db-lookup, then it needs to include that. Based on how much you want/need to encode, you may need to pick the right kind of barcode. Question: "Should I add a new attribute for the UPC/SKU?" - Do you mean a new property? If so: again - "it depends ...".

There are specifications that comprehensively standardize the data model handled by the retail industry. Although it is a conceptual thing that is not directly related to the program, it may be useful as a reference. OPERATIONAL DATA MODEL
